# Use Ribbon Interface in Open Source Applications

Tags: c++, user-interface, ribbon

Are there any open source implementations of the Ribbon interface available? I need to use them in a GPL licensed software, so the library should be compatible with GPL. The software is in VC++ 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[wxWidgets](http://wxwidgets.org/) supports ribbon interfaces as well.

Comment: +1, their license page (http://www.wxwidgets.org/about/newlicen.htm) specifically mentions that you are able to use wxWidgets in GPL'd software.

Answer (score 3):

If running on Vista or Windows 7 then MS supply a ribbon SDK.  There is a superb WTL article on this [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/RibbonUI.aspx).